# Share fragment layout between activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity which uses fragments. There are 3 fragments that will be displayed after each other (1. search fields, 2. results list, 3. item details)

This is the layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="myapp.FirstActivity">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container_common"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

A second activity extends this first activity. This second activity, however, needs to display more search fields.

The onCreate method of the second activity is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //Create the first fragment
    searchFragment= new SearchFragment();
    //show the fragment...
}
```

So, what I was going to do is: add the extra search fields in a layout in the search fields fragment. This layout will have visibility `gone`.

Then, when creating the second activity, I make this layout visible.

What and where is the correct way to let the fragment know that it needs to display the layout?

Comment: Inflate that view in second activity and make it visible

Comment: @AnandSavjani where exactly to inflate? in the fragment itself? but then, how do I tell the fragment (through the activity)?

Comment: In second activity you have to inflate and take FragmentActivity for it.

Comment: @AnandSavjani I don't understand. Can you provide an example?

Comment: In Second Activity take it as FragmentActivity and override onCreateView method in second Activity. Inflate your searchview in Second Activity and set visibility of that control as Visible . Hope you will understand.